# Should I flag comments, that have been incorporated into an edit?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

A few days ago, I flagged this comment as "no longer needed":

> [catch IOException not the generic exception.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070350/errorstream-in-httpurlconnection/7524681#comment16068142_7524681)

The comment is a *good* and *valuable* feedback (and has 4 upvotes) - but it had already been incoporated into [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7524681/2) of the answer.

Why was the flag declined? Should I flag similar cases in future?

Comment: Use a custom flag if you must flag these cases. This kind of thing is not terribly hard to miss, and at first glance it can look to the mod like you are trying to get rid of a useful comment. With a custom flag you can explain "the content of this comment has already been incorporated into the post with an edit".

Comment: @yivi This makes sense to me. Do you think, in this particular case, I should flag this one comment *again*, as "moderator attention"?

Comment: You could. Pretty sure it will be honoured, but I have no diamonds near my username. I guess since the post has been edited already the comment can be distracting and kinda noisy.

Comment: Errors happen, that comment can indeed go and I’ve deleted it now.

Comment: Now you do, @yivi. Two diamonds, right below your user name. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago, the comment flags were working differently on stackoverflow. The old description was quite clear about those cases:

> obsolete — a comment that is no longer relevant because **it has been
>   addressed by an edit to the post**, clarified by additional comments, or
>   contains no context because it references deleted content

Comments that have already been incorporated into an edit can be noisy and can distract or confuse readers.

Flag those comments. However it might be advisable (especially for comments with several upvotes) to use the "moderator attention" type of flag, if the situation is not obvious.